# Gradle task in configuratoin phase has dependency on a task in execution phase

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, lifecycle

i have 3 different build files,
**prodbuild.gradle**, **build.gradle** and **build.xml**

and the hierarchy is, i will first call **prodbuild.gradle**

```
// Script used by Prod builds, 

// Import development gradle file for basic build
apply from: 'build.gradle'

task prodX {
...
}

task prodY {
...
}

task prodZ {
...
}
```

as per my understanding this is calling **build.gradle**

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml')

task A {
...
}

task B {
...
}
```

and this is calling **build.xml**

```
<target name="antX" >
        ...
        ...
</target>

<target name="antY" dependson "antX">
        ...
        ...
</target>
```

##### Problem statement

target **antX** uses the directory created by task **B** in **build.gradle**, but the line

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml')
```

is executed in configuration phase, and at that time task **A** and task **B** are not executed, this is causing the issue,
i tried to avoid this by changing the **build.gradle** as

```
task importAntBuild (){
    doLast {
        ant.importBuild('build.xml')
    }
}
```

but task **prodX** is dependent on target **antY**, since i made **importAntBuild** to run at last this will again cause the problem.

this is the first time i am working on a gradle project, correct me if my understanding is wrong, any help is appreciated.

PS : all of this cycle was working fine with gradle 2.3, this issue is observed after i upgraded it to gradle 7.4